# Exception handling in facade service

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception, architecture

I'm developing web application using SpringMVC according to 3tier architecture (Presentation, Application, Domain layers). Also there is a facade service on presentation layer and each request from controller to application service goes through facade service (Contorller -> FacadeService -> ApplicationService). If I'm getting an exception in Application or Domain layer I should display it in UI. That's how it is implemented now.

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/password/change")
public String processChangePasswordRequest(ChangePasswordForm form, BindingResult bindingResult){
    ChangePasswordReqStatus status = facadeService.requestChangePassword(
            form.getOld(),
            form.getPassword()
    );

    if(status == ChangePasswordReqStatus.PASSWORD_MISMATCH)
        bindingResult.rejectValue("oldPassword", "password.mismatch", "Wrong password");
    return "change_password";
```

**FacadeService**

```
@Override
public ChangePasswordReqStatus requestChangePassword(Password old,   Password password) {
    try{
        accountService.changePassword(old, password);
    }catch (PasswordMismatchException ex){
        return ChangePasswordReqStatus.PASSWORD_MISMATCH;
    }
    return ChangePasswordReqStatus.OK;
}
```

But I'm not sure wether I can catch exceptions in facade service or maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the exceptions being thrown by the account service are not checked exceptions, a better and much cleaner design would be to not catch any exceptions at all. Use [ControllerAdvice](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) and handle all exceptions there as well as response logic (what response status will be return, and message etc).

You could do something like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {
  public static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW = "error";

  @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
  public ModelAndView
  defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) throws Exception {
    // If the exception is annotated with @ResponseStatus rethrow it and let
    // the framework handle it - like the OrderNotFoundException example
    // at the start of this post.
    // AnnotationUtils is a Spring Framework utility class.
    if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation
                (e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null)
      throw e;

    // Otherwise setup and send the user to a default error-view.
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("exception", e);
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
    mav.setViewName(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
    return mav;
  }
}
```